# checkbox in titlepane header

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I would like to add a checkbox to the header of a TitlePane using JavaScript, which when checked will be able to check all checkboxes in the TitlePane content. I have managed to add the checkbox by the following code:

```
var cb = new dijit.form.CheckBox({name:"checkBox"}).placeAt(dijit.byId("someid").focusNode, "end");
```

However, marking the checkbox as checked activates the open/close action of the TitlePane. Not sure how to separate the action of checkbox from the action of TitlePane.

Based on Jeremiah's suggestion, I used this code :

```
var selectGrp1DNew = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
    id : "grp1DButtonNew",
    onClick: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        //function to identify child checkboxes and turn then on/off
        chkGrp(this);
    }

    //group1D is the TitlePane id
}).placeAt(dijit.byId("group1D").focusNode, "end");
```

Please help,
Samir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using event.stopPropagation() in your checkbox's click event handler:  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/events.html

**Update**
Looking at your updated code and comment, I suggest connecting to the CheckBox's onChange event instead.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for me, but added another issue. The TitlePane's open/close action is not working anymore. Any thoughts what could have gone wrong? I have not worked on any element other than the TitlePane and the checkboxes within it.

Comment: @samirg Suggestion added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately, it did not work. It functions well using the onClick event and works separately from TitlePane's opn/close action. The TitlePane does not open at all. I do not get any warnings in the console. However, the class attribute of the TitlePane's Title element does show 'Open' and 'Close' when the header is clicked.

Comment: I figured out the problem and solved it. I had placed the Title Panes under a 'Form' div. Changing the div type to "dojox.widget.TitleGroup' resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `TitlePane` header can contain a checkbox. Like this:

```
 var titlePane1 = new TitlePane({
        id: "titlePane1",
        title: "input type='checkbox'/>",
        content: "Collapse me!" ,
        open:false
    }, "titlePane1");
```